# Why does the navs hamburger-icon not appear on mobile?

Tags: jquery, html, css, navigation

I have been fiddling with my navigation menu for a while now with no luck. I am uncertain why and would appreciate any and all insight. I do not think the script is at fault, but I have no idea why it does not show the hamburger icon when the screen is smaller. I feel like I have tried everything by now, it is really starting to give me quite the headache. It should be so simple, but it refuses to work.

The menu is, quite simply, supposed to show the hamburger icon on smaller screens, and when you click on it, the full nav-menu slides down.

The nav-list does disappear but there is no hamburger-icon so I can´t make it reappear on smaller screens.

LINK TO MY CODEPEN: https://codepen.io/Pinchofginger/pen/eYmydBo

```html
<div class="nav">
    <nav class="main-navigation">
        <a href="#"><img id="logo"src="https://www.vindrosen-huset.dk/media/zoo/images/Angstforeningen_29df0951c1c6886d2b89cb5249a05da4.png" alt="alt tekst"></a>
        <div class="menu-list">
          <a href="#">Hjem &nbsp;<i class="fas fa-home"></i></a></a>   

          <div class="subnav">
            <a href="www.angstforeningen.dk/index.php?page=hvorfor-en-angstforening">Emner på siden  &nbsp; <i class="fas fa-list"></i></a></div>
           <div class="subnav">
            <a href="www.angstforeningen.dk/uploads/tryksager/pjecer/Panikangst.pdf">Folder &nbsp;<i class="fas fa-file-download"></i></a></div>

           <div class="subnav">
            <a href="tegn-paa-smerte.html">Kontakt os &nbsp;<i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>

             </a></div>        

        <i id="mobile-menu" class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </nav>

  </div></div>


    <!-- Ikon kit -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/52c7af8f48.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

```css
.nav {
  background-color: #144e75;
}

#logo {
  margin-top: -35%;
}

.main-navigation {
  letter-spacing: .1em; /* Rummet mellem bogstaver */
  height: 20px;
  display: flex; /* flexbox */
  justify-content: space-between; /* Distribuere delene ligeligt på pladsen */
}

.main-navigation img {
  height: 60px;
}

.main-navigation a {
  padding: 30px 10px;
  float: left;
  color: #f6933b;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 15px;
}

.main-navigation a:hover {
  color: white;
}

#mobile-menu {
  display: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.subnav {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  #mobile-menu {
    display: flex;
  }

  .main-navigation a {
    float: none;
  }

  .menu-list {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 80px;
    border-top: 5px solid #0072ce;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #0072ce;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
  }

  .menu-list a {
    display: block;
    padding: 16px;
  }

  .subnav {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }
}
```

```js
$("#mobile-menu").click(function() {
    $(".menu-list").slideToggle();

    $("a").click(function() {
        $(".menu-list").slideUp();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your structure the hamburger is a child to the div that has class of menu-list and because you hide menu-list you also hide all childs

so you need to get it out to display

```js
$("#mobile-menu").click(function() {
    $(".menu-list").slideToggle();

    $("a").click(function() {
        $(".menu-list").slideUp();
    });

});
```

```css
.nav { background-color: #144e75;}
#logo {margin-top: -35%;}
.main-navigation {
  letter-spacing: 0.1em; /*Rummet mellem bogstaver*/
  height: 20px;
  display: flex; /*flexbox*/
  justify-content: space-between;/*Distribuere delene ligeligt på pladsen*/
 }
  .main-navigation img {
    height: 60px;
  }
  .main-navigation a {
    padding: 30px 10px;
    float: left;
   color: #f6933b;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0 15px;
  }
  .main-navigation a:hover {
    color: white;  }

  #mobile-menu {
    display: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-right: 10px;   }

  .subnav {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;   }
  
  @media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    #mobile-menu { display: flex;flex-direction:row-reverse; }
    .main-navigation a { float: none; }
    
    .menu-list {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 80px;
      border-top: 5px solid #0072ce;
      border-bottom: 5px solid #0072ce;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #fff;
    }
    .menu-list a { display: block;
      padding: 16px; }
    
    .subnav {
      float: none;
      display: inline;
    }   }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
    <nav class="main-navigation">
        <a href="#"><img id="logo"src="https://www.vindrosen-huset.dk/media/zoo/images/Angstforeningen_29df0951c1c6886d2b89cb5249a05da4.png" alt="alt tekst"></a>
        <div class="menu-list">
          <a href="#">Hjem &nbsp;<i class="fas fa-home"></i></a></a>   
          
          <div class="subnav">
            <a href="www.angstforeningen.dk/index.php?page=hvorfor-en-angstforening">Emner på siden  &nbsp; <i class="fas fa-list"></i></a></div>
           <div class="subnav">
            <a href="www.angstforeningen.dk/uploads/tryksager/pjecer/Panikangst.pdf">Folder &nbsp;<i class="fas fa-file-download"></i></a></div>
      
           <div class="subnav">
            <a href="tegn-paa-smerte.html">Kontakt os &nbsp;<i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
              
             </a></div>        
          
        
      </nav>

  </div>
<i id="mobile-menu" class="fas fa-bars"></i>
</div>


    <!-- Ikon kit -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/52c7af8f48.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Codepen, `#mobile-menu` is inside `#menulist` which has `display: none`. Move it out and it is visible

Answer (score 1):

I just move `#mobile-menu` outside the `.menulist` div.

Reason behind why it not appear is `.menu-list` already display none and hamburger-icon inside the `.menu-list` that why is not appear.

```js
$("#mobile-menu").click(function() {
    $(".menu-list").slideToggle();

    $("a").click(function() {
        $(".menu-list").slideUp();
    });

});
```

```css
.nav { background-color: #144e75;}
#logo {margin-top: -35%;}
.main-navigation {
  letter-spacing: 0.1em; /*Rummet mellem bogstaver*/
  height: 20px;
  display: flex; /*flexbox*/
  justify-content: space-between;/*Distribuere delene ligeligt på pladsen*/
 }
  .main-navigation img {
    height: 60px;
  }
  .main-navigation a {
    padding: 30px 10px;
    float: left;
   color: #f6933b;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0 15px;
  }
  .main-navigation a:hover {
    color: white;  }

  #mobile-menu {
    display: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-right: 10px;   }

  .subnav {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;   }
  
  @media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    #mobile-menu { display: flex; }
    .main-navigation a { float: none; }
    
    .menu-list {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 80px;
      border-top: 5px solid #0072ce;
      border-bottom: 5px solid #0072ce;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #fff;
    }
    .menu-list a { display: block;
      padding: 16px; }
    
    .subnav {
      float: none;
      display: inline;
    }   }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
    <nav class="main-navigation">
        <a href="#"><img id="logo"src="https://www.vindrosen-huset.dk/media/zoo/images/Angstforeningen_29df0951c1c6886d2b89cb5249a05da4.png" alt="alt tekst"></a>
        <div class="menu-list">
          <a href="#">Hjem &nbsp;<i class="fas fa-home"></i></a></a>   
          
          <div class="subnav">
            <a href="www.angstforeningen.dk/index.php?page=hvorfor-en-angstforening">Emner på siden  &nbsp; <i class="fas fa-list"></i></a></div>
           <div class="subnav">
            <a href="www.angstforeningen.dk/uploads/tryksager/pjecer/Panikangst.pdf">Folder &nbsp;<i class="fas fa-file-download"></i></a></div>
      
           <div class="subnav">
            <a href="tegn-paa-smerte.html">Kontakt os &nbsp;<i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
              
             </a></div>        
          
      </nav>

  </div>

        <i id="mobile-menu" class="fas fa-bars"></i>

</div>


    <!-- Ikon kit -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/52c7af8f48.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```